Get all slopes of $x^3 + 2y^2 -2xy = 0$ at $(0,0)$
Consider the curve with the equation $x^3 + 2y^2 -2xy = 0$. If we want to find the slope at $(0,0)$, we can differentiate implicitly and substitute $(0,0)$. This gives $y' = 0$ and all seems well, but there is another slope of the curve at $(0,0)$ equal to $1$. How can we get that slope?
Is there a way to answer that question assuming only the rudimentary understanding of calculus (i.e., one year of calculus)?

@coffeemath I agree, that's how you could do it. However, in Calculus I it is common to differentiate implicitly and then substitute to find the derivative. There's nothing special about $(0,0)$, I would run into the same issue at any other point. Is there a way to get to the answer without parametrization?

Given an implicit curve like yours, where one is interested in $(0,0)$ and the implicit derivative is not defined there, need some other approach than just implicit derivatives.

I think the answer below is right - you cannot really use implicit differentiation to even conclude $y'=0$ is one of the slopes. Without parametrizing (which is a first year calculus topic btw) it is very difficult to rigorously justify any tangents near the origin.

I think the problem is that you cannot really use implicit differentiation to find the slope at $(0, 0).$
Because through implicit differentiation:
$$3x ^ 2 + 4y \frac{dy}{dx} - 2y - 2x \frac{dy}{dx} = 0,$$
which rearranges to
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2y - 3x ^ 2}{4y-2x}.$$
But both the numerator and the denominator are zero at $x = 0, y = 0$, so I don't really know whether you can just substitute in the values to find the gradient.
I think another way to find the gradients is to just express $y$ in terms of $x$, so that
\begin{align}
y &= \frac{2x \pm \sqrt{4x ^ 2 - 8x ^ 3}}{4} \\
&= \frac{2x \pm 2x\sqrt{1 - 2x}}{4} \\
&= \frac{x \pm x\sqrt{1 - 2x}}{2}.
\end{align}
It follows that
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1 \pm (\sqrt{1 - 2x} - \frac{x}{\sqrt{1 - 2x}})}{2}.
\end{align}
Finally, substituting in $x = 0$ should give $0$ and $1$ as gradients.
Now thinking about it, I wonder what the solution should be if the equation was in higher powers of $x$ and $y$, because in that case the quadratic formula wouldn't work. Perhaps someone more experienced could help answer this?
